# What should I know in JavaScript before learning AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I recently tried to learn AngularJS. I thought it would be easy since I have a programming background. I was wrong. I actually never really programmed in JavaScript and it's puzzling when I try to understand Angular concepts like promises to call my web services.

The thing is I unfortunately don't have unlimited time, so it's difficult for me to learn the whole JavaScript language.

That's why I'd like to know what are the main things I absolutely need to understand (concepts, syntax, ...) to be comfortable with AngularJS.

Comment: Hi David. While this is an interesting question, it isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. We prefer questions here that are specific and answerable - for example, if you have an Angular problem involving code, that would be great. This question is likely to be put on hold, though you may garner some small bits of guidance in the comments.

Comment: I think [this is a good starting point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: most important thing in angular is understanding prototypical object inheritance. If you can't mentally visualize nested scopes, angular isn't for you

Comment: Functions, callbacks, objects, properties, arrays, DOM manipulation, variable scope, `this`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You definitely want to know JavaScript, and pretty well, to use Angular. Otherwise, you'll end up copying and pasting code and won't really get how it works. It will have you pulling your hair out. Angular seems to expect that you have a good grasp of JavaScript's functions and objects, as well as how variable scopes work.

If you're already programming, a good quick read is '[JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do)'. It's not a beginner book and it's a little old, but will bring you up to speed quickly if you already understand basic programming concepts.